# Upload files in wordpress

Tags: customization, uploads, media

What is the best way to upload files in wordpress? How can I upload multiple files at a time like media uploads in wordpress?

Comment: Maybe this post is helpful for you: http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/

As you can see, some custom work needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WP Multi File Uploader](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-file-uploader/) plugin that uses AJAX. Havent tried it by myself yet but it should solve your problem.

Comment: can I do this without using a plugin rather using only wordpress functions and included libraries?

Comment: Not what I know of but you could use this plugin to upload all your pictures and then disable it. And I think there is a way to upload thru FTP and force wordpress to recognize the files. But I suggest you to use a plugin, thats how I would do it. [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) @Md Toufiqul Islam